# Firebase Validation

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

I'm just starting with Firebase and doing some simple testing.  I'm having trouble with validation.

Here is some sample code:

```
var Firebase = require("firebase");

var myFirebaseRef = new Firebase("https://familytrial.firebaseio.com/");

myFirebaseRef.child("families").on("value", function(snapshot) {
  console.log("Something changed!");
  console.log("%j", snapshot.val());
  console.log("\n\n\n");

}, function(err) {
  console.log("Something failed!");
  console.log(err);
});

setTimeout( function() {

  myFirebaseRef.child('families').push({
    "familyName" : "Jones",
    "members" : {
      "givenName" : "Jim",
      "calledName" : "Koolaid",
      "parent" : true
    }
  }, function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log("\nAn error occurred");
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
}, 3000);


setTimeout( function() {

  myFirebaseRef.child('families').push({
    "familyName" : "The Jones Have a Ridiculously Long Family Name That Should Get Rejected",
    "members" : {
      "givenName" : "Jim",
      "calledName" : "Koolaid",
      "parent" : true
    }
  }, function(err) {
    if(err) {
      console.log("\nAn error occurred");
      console.log(err);
    }
  })
}, 3000);
```

This code works just fine when the validations are:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read" : true,
    ".write" : true
  }
}
```

However, when I try to validate anything in families, I get permission errors or the validation simply doesn't seem to restrict input.

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".write": true,
    ".read": true,
    "families": {
      "familyName": {
        ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length < 50"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I would expect that validation rule to allow the first push to 'families' and reject the second.  However, it accepts both pushes.

What am I doing wrong with that validation?

Thanks,
Justin

Comment: What does the data look like? My first guess would be that your data is families/$familyid/familyName and that your security rules are off by one level.

Comment: You can see that above.  But basically `{"familyName":"Jones","members":{"givenName":"Jim","calledName":"Koolaid","parent":true}}`  And yes, your comment does explain the problem.  I was trying to validate a property of a member under families, not a direct property of the `families` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Kato alluded to the answer.  Here's the complete explanation.

I was trying to create a member of the `families` object.  Like this:

`{"familyName":"Jones","members":{"givenName":"Jim","calledName":"Koolaid","parent":true}}`

So, that would create a structure like :

```
{
  "families": {
    "some_object_id": {
      "familyName": "Jones",
      "members": {
        "givenName": "Jim",
        "calledName": "Koolaid",
        "parent": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, my validation rules were for validating a `familyname` property on the `families` object.
That validation rule would have worked great for something like this:

```
{
  "families": {
    "familyName": "Jones"    
  }
}
```

This is not what I wanted.  My correct validation, needed to be like this:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": false,
    ".write": false,
    "families": {
      ".read": true,
      "$families_id": {
        ".write": "!data.exists() && newData.exists()",
        "familyName": {
          ".validate": "newData.isString() && newData.val().length > 1 && newData.val().length < 50"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```